# Min and max length of the whole string using regular expressions on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex

I need to check if user login is valid. It can be both email and usual string with "." and "-" symbols in it. But it can't start with these symbols. Min length of login is 3 symbols and max is 35. I've written an regexp:

```
NSString *loginRegex = @"(?=[A-Za-z0-9.-]{3,35})((^[^.-][A-Za-z0-9.-]+
@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z0-9.-]{2,4})|^[^.-][A-Za-z0-9.-]+)";
```

Everything's fine with min length but validating max length fails. Please, help. What I've done wrong?

Comment: Is that a continuous regex?

Comment: yes, I just split it here in 2 lines to make more readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the `@` symbol in your assertion character class.
Beyond that, you have to add start/end string anchors to constrain the
length requirement.

Adding that and refactoring, it works out to this:

```
"^(?=[A-Za-z0-9.@-]{3,35}$)([^.-][A-Za-z0-9.-]+(?:@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z0-9.-]{2,4})?)$"
```

Formatted:

```
 # Raw, compressed:  ^(?=[A-Za-z0-9.@-]{3,35}$)([^.-][A-Za-z0-9.-]+(?:@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z0-9.-]{2,4})?)$

 ^ 
 (?= [A-Za-z0-9.@-]{3,35} $ )
 (                             # (1 start)
      [^.-] 
      [A-Za-z0-9.-]+ 
      (?:
           @ 
           [A-Za-z0-9.-]+ 
           \. 
           [A-Za-z0-9.-]{2,4} 
      )?
 )                             # (1 end)
 $
```

Comment: Thank You! Worked perfectly for me.

Comment: But I think using "@-" instead of "-@" in the beginning is more correct.


    `"^(?=[A-Za-z0-9.@-]{3,35}$)([^.-][A-Za-z0-9.-]+(?:@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z0-9.-]{2,4})?)$"`